# Everyone meets everyone else.

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a game in which $i$ players at a time can play, and I want to organize a tournament, inviting $n$ people. We play in rounds, so of course $i$ has to divide $n$ because winning by default is boring. Each round then consists of $n/i$ games played simultaneously, and of course no player plays more than one game at any one time.

Now, to make iot interesting, I choose $n$ so that $(i-1)$ also divides $(n-1)$, and let the tournament consist of $\frac{n-1}{i-1}$ rounds in total. Is it possible in general to seat players so that everyone plays against everyone else exactly once during the tournament?

The background is that yesterday I took part in a tournament in a three-player game, with 15 participants. After five rounds I'm pretty certain no one had met anyone else twice, and I was curious whether it would possible to keep that record up for two more rounds. However, the tournament ended there, and I didn't pester the host with my petty theoretical mathematical questions.

Comment: It seems that a very similar problem was already posed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58922/rearrangement-of-groups-such-that-no-two-members-meet-again?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your specific case of the $3$-player $7$-round tournament.  The answer is yes.  In fact, this is the famous [Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem).  In general, you're seeking a *resolvable BIBD* (balanced incomplete block design).

> Fifteen young ladies in a school walk out three abreast for seven days in succession: it is required to arrange them daily so that no two shall walk twice abreast.

Here's the solution on Wikipedia:

[image: A solution to the Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem]