# How can I schedule a round robin-like boardgame tournament, where every player has to move to each of the tables and play each of the other players?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like some help in figuring out how to set up the play schedule for an up-coming boardgame tournament.  I have 16 players to schedule. There are 4 different tables with each table containing a different boardgame.  Each table with seat 4 players at a time. Players will need to play each game (so will have to move to each table) and compete against all other players at least once. Is this possible? If so, could you provide a formula or diagram?

I have read all of the other questions pertaining to "round robins" but each of those does not seem to answer the problem of moving each player to each table.

I would love any and all help with this problem.

Thank you very much.

Rebekah

Comment: do you want for each person to play each other person in at least one sport on in all of the sports?

Comment: Yes. As Henrik pointed out, the detail of having each player move to each table is the hangup that I am having.   To explain the reason for the moving to each table look at it this way.  If table #1 is Scrabble, Table #2 is Sorry, Table #3 is Yahtzee, and Table #4 is Monopoly and we use the Rounds that "The Emperor of Ice Cream" suggested, player A will always have to play Scrabble, Player B will have to play 3 games of Sorry and so forth with players C and D. So again, the question is how to rotate all the players so all players will move to each table & meet each other player at least once?

Comment: Yes you can, but in how many rounds ? It would require a minimum of five rounds for me to meet 15 other players 3 at a time, but this would not be likely to get everyone else meeting and especially at different tables. This post http://math.stackexchange.com/q/58927 suggests an analytic solution may not exist. So if you get close to five rounds you are doing well. I think you can adapt a Howell 4 table bridge movement to achieve this result in seven rounds by putting the players in pairs and having an extra copy of three of the games (if that helps ?).