# How to get a even distribution of play offs in a "round robin" tournament?

Tags: logic

I have a round robin (everyone must play everyone) competition with an unknown number of players. It consists of games where up to and preferably always 4 players play against each other. Each player must play each other player at least once and preferably never again. The amount of break each player gets must be as even as possible between games and players.

I have found solutions for similar problems [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827666/scheduling-a-round-robin-tournament-4-way-games) and [here](https://cs.stanford.edu/~warut/roundrobin.pdf) but none solve the last condition.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relative importance of the goals.  You say, "The distribution of the games each player play's **must** be as even as possible through out the entire tournament."  Why doesn't this mean "Every player must play the same number of games?"  What can supersede this requirement?

Comment: Every player must play the same number of games but the rest time between games must be as similar as possible for all players.