# Adaptation of round-robin tournaments for 4 player games.

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a "fair" matchup system for a competition where $16$ players participate in a 4- player game. I would like to emulate the advantages of a round-robin system For example if my game were a 2-player one, I could easily make a $15$-round tournament, with each player facing a different opponent on each round. At the end of the tournament, each player would have faced all opponents exactly once, so none of the players faced a stronger opposition than any other player. A total of $120$ games would have been played in total.

This simply doesn't work in a game with more players. If I wanted to go through every possible matchup in a 3-player game, I'd need $560$ games (more than $100$ rounds), and with four players, I'd need $1820$ games (in other words, each player would participate in $455$ games). I've considered switching to something based on the "Swiss" format used in chess, but that also has its downsides.

My question is, what would be the shortest pairing method that would make each player on the competition face every opponent the same number of times? Does it apply to a different number of competitors? And no a game of $n$ players? It still wouldn't be totally "fair", as a cetain combination of opponents could be tougher than another, but it'd definitely be an improvement.

**PS**: As three opponents are played at each round and there are $15$ opponents for each player. The number of rounds played should  therefore be a multiple of $5$, but I don't know if it would be possible to do it with exactly $5$ rounds (after all, if there were $20$ rather than $16$, you'd defintely need at least $19$ rounds

Comment: It might be possible to have a five-round tournament in this case, where each player plays against each other once.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827666/scheduling-a-round-robin-tournament-4-way-games?rq=1