# You have N people and groups of K, what is the minimal number iterations of groups until everyone meets everybody?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, you have 30 people and groups of 5, what is the minimal number iterations of groups until everyone meets everybody?

If you have 4 people (numbered 1-4) and groups of 2, then you need 3 iterations:

```
iteration 1 groups: (1,2), (3,4)
iteration 2 groups: (1,3), (2,4)
iteration 3 groups: (1,4), (2,3)
```

If you have 6 people and groups of 3, then you need 4 iterations, e.g.:

```
iteration 1 groups: (1,2,3), (4,5,6)
iteration 2 groups: (1,4,5), (2,3,6)
iteration 3 groups: (1,6,3), (2,4,5)
iteration 4 groups: (3,4,1), (2,5,6)
```

How to solve this for n=30 and k=5?  Is 10 iterations provably not sufficient for n=30 and k=5?  Would a greedy (non-exact) algorithm be a good approach?

Comment: The case $N=15,K=3$ is the famous [Kirkman schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem).

Comment: read up on your steiner systems, block designs, balanced incomplete block designs,...

Comment: The easy lower bound is that you need at least $\frac{N-1}{K-1}$ rounds. But sometimes you need more.

Comment: Can we assume that $K$ perfectly divides $N$? In other words you are not interested in cases where we have a remainder group with $<K$ members. For example you are not interested in cases: (10 people, groups of 9),  (5 people, groups of 2), (33 people, groups of 10).

Comment: Sure, you can assume that.  I'm interested in both cases, but I'm really itching to reward the bounty.

Comment: Please somebody post an answer, even if it is just a slight elaboration on @ThomasAndrews comment, I want to reward the bounty before it expires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an open problem (at least within this community). See for example [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58922/rearrangement-of-groups-such-that-no-two-members-meet-again?rq=1).

I'll assume that $K$ perfectly divides $N$, so that we have $\frac{N}K$ groups each having $K$ members.

I have a partial answer. It took me a while to arrive there. First let's look at the lower bound that Thomas mentions in his comment.

We have $N$ people in total and in essence we are interested in their pairings. If people $x,y$ have been in the same group we consider them paired (they have met). In total we have $\frac{N(N-1)}2$ pairings/meetings that need to happen Explanation: each of the $N$ people have to meet another $N-1$ people, but if we count this way, we are counting each meeting twice (1 meets 2, and 2 meets 1). So we divide the product by $2$ to get the count of pairings.

Now, within a small group of $K$ people we have $\frac{K(K-1)}{2}$ pairings. And we have $\frac{N}K$ of these groups. So in total we have $\frac{N}K \cdot \frac{K(K-1)}{2} = \frac{N(K-1)}{2}$ pairings for each configuration (you call them iterations). So how many configurations/iterations we will need at the very least?

$$\frac{\text{total pairings}}{\text{pairings in each iteration}} = \frac{\frac{N(N-1)}2}{\frac{N(K-1)}{2}} = \frac{N-1}{K-1}$$

Moreover, since this quantity might not be an integer we should take its ceiling: $\left\lceil\frac{N-1}{K-1}\right\rceil$

So for your specific case we would need at least $\left\lceil\frac{30-1}{5-1}\right\rceil = \lceil 7.25 \rceil = 8$ iterations. You have found one solution with $10$ iterations (I have not checked it, but I'll assume it is correct.) Can we perhaps find one with $9$, or even with $8$?

I started approaching the problem for simple cases. Let's first look at the case where $K=2$. We have $N/2$ groups and it is easy to find a solution where everyone meets everyone else. We just keep one of the members of the group constant and then we change the other member by shifting through the other groups one by one. This will require $N-1$ iterations, which is equal to our lower bound (for $K=2$), so we know we have an optimal solution. Let's consider another case where $K = N/2$, so we just have two groups. This is a bit trickier. For $N=4, K=2$ this falls under the $K=2$ category and we know how to deal with. For $N=6, K=3$ you have found a solution with 4 iterations. However, the lower bound is $\left\lceil\frac{6-1}{3-1}\right\rceil = \lceil 2.5 \rceil = 3$. So could we perhaps do better than $4$? The answer is no, the actual optimum is $4$. I do not want to go into a proof here, since the post will become too long, but you can easily see how is this the case as there are limited options to the "moves/swaps" you can do from one iteration to the next.
How about $N=8, K=4$? There we can find a solution with $3$ iterations. 
$$(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8) \rightarrow (5,6,3,4),(1,2,7,8) \rightarrow (1,2,5,6),(3,4,7,8)$$
In general, if $K=N/2$ is even, the optimum solution is $3$ iterations (matching the lower bound), and if $K=N/2$ is odd, the optimum solution is $4$ iterations. So we know *how* to construct the optimal solutions for the $K=N/2$ case, and interestingly we have found that in some cases the optimum is +1 above the lower bound, while in other cases it is the lower bound.

The next interesting case happens when $N=9$ and the only $K$ we can choose is $K=3$. The lower bound is $4$ in this case. Is there a solution with $4$ iterations? Lets's represent the people/numbers in an array form, where the rows are the groups we are forming (each having $K$ members) and hence we have $N/K$ rows and $K$ columns. Any configuration/iteration can be our starting point, let's start with one where the numbers are "in order" just for ease of representation, and better following the subsequent "moves".
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}
$$

Now we can choose the numbers in the first column and shift them among the rows (i.e., move the first to the second, the second to the third, and the third to the first row). Notice that there is no point in choosing two numbers from the same row to move them together (at the same row), as this is equivalent to moving the remaining number towards the "opposite" direction. And of course there is no point moving three numbers in unison (i.e. swapping rows). So if we take a single column and do this row shift then we end up with $2$ new pairings in each row, so in total we will have $6$ new pairing with the new iteration. Initially this is what I did as my first move and proceeding with similar moves I ended up with a solution of $5$ iterations. But can we do better? Each iteration has $9$ pairings. Can our second iteration/configuration create $9$ **new** configurations instead of just $6$? In other words, can we create a configuration where all the pairings are new? Yes we can. Here's how: we can still shift the first column +1 rows, but we can also shift the second column +2 rows. This will create $9$ new pairings. Then in the third iteration we can continue the shift. After this point we are done with this move (if we do it one more time it will bring us back to the initial iteration). Here's how it looks:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}2 & 3 \\
\color{red}4 & \color{blue}5 & 6 \\
\color{red}7 & \color{blue}8 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\; \rightarrow \;
\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}7 & \color{blue}5 & 3 \\
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}8 & 6 \\
\color{red}4 & \color{blue}2 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\; \rightarrow \;
\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}4 & \color{blue}8 & 3 \\
\color{red}7 & \color{blue}2 & 6 \\
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}5 & 9 \\
\end{array}
$$

Notice that each number in each of the columns has been paired with **all** other numbers at different columns. The only thing that remains is pairing it with the numbers in its own column. Since the table is square we are do exactly this by making the columns the rows and we are done. This is the last move.
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}1 & \color{red}4 & \color{red}7 \\
\color{blue}2 & \color{blue}5 & \color{blue}8 \\
3 & 6 & 9 \\
\end{array}
$$

What is more important is that **we see how this procedure can be generalized** for any number $N$ that is a square and $K = \sqrt{N}$. **UPDATE**: No, I have found that this does not generalise for every square $N$. I tried it for $N=16, K=4$ and it does not work. More importantly, there is **no** rearrangement scheme (with columns keeping the same elements) able to create maximum new pairings for each of the four first iterations. However the algorithm works for $N=25, K=5$. I believe that in general it works when $\sqrt{N}$ is a **prime number**. This is the general algorithm:

- Start with the numbers ordered in a table of $K=\sqrt{N}$ rows and $K$ columns. The rows denote the groups that we partition our $N$ numbers each time.
- Shift the numbers in the first column $+1$ row, the numbers in the second column $+2$ rows, the numbers in the $i^{th}$ column $+i$ rows, and finally the numbers in the $(K-1)^{th}$ column $+K-1$ rows. We do not move the numbers in the $K^{th}$ column (or you can view it as moving them $+K$ rows which has no effect)
- The above moves create one new iteration. Repeat the above procedure $K-1$ times. This will create $K$ iterations (including the initial one)
- Finally for the $K+1$ iteration make the columns of the table to be the rows.

With these $K+1$ iterations we created all possible pairings, **and we know this is the optimal solution because it matches the lower bound.** Lower bound is: $\frac{N-1}{K-1} = \frac{K^2 -1}{K-1} = \frac{(K+1)\cdot(K-1)}{K-1} = K+1$

Here are the $6$ iterations the algorithm produces for the case $N=25, K=5$. I'll use digits 1-9 along with letters A-P to describe the items/people. This way all items are one character long, which I believe makes tabular representation clearer.

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}2 & \color{green}3 &\color{orange}4 & 5 \\
\color{red}6 & \color{blue}7 & \color{green}8 &\color{orange}9 & A \\
\color{red}B & \color{blue}C & \color{green}D &\color{orange}E & F \\
\color{red}G & \color{blue}H & \color{green}I &\color{orange}J & K \\
\color{red}L & \color{blue}M & \color{green}N &\color{orange}O & P \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\color{red}L & \color{blue}H & \color{green}D &\color{orange}9 & 5 \\
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}M & \color{green}I &\color{orange}E & A \\
\color{red}6 & \color{blue}2 & \color{green}N &\color{orange}J & F \\
\color{red}B & \color{blue}7 & \color{green}3 &\color{orange}O & K \\
\color{red}G & \color{blue}C & \color{green}8 &\color{orange}4 & P \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\color{red}G & \color{blue}7 & \color{green}N &\color{orange}E & 5 \\
\color{red}L & \color{blue}C & \color{green}3 &\color{orange}J & A \\
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}H & \color{green}8 &\color{orange}O & F \\
\color{red}6 & \color{blue}M & \color{green}D &\color{orange}4 & K \\
\color{red}B & \color{blue}2 & \color{green}I &\color{orange}9 & P \\
\end{array}
\text{ }\\
\text{ }\\
\text{ }\\
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\color{red}B & \color{blue}M & \color{green}8 &\color{orange}J & 5 \\
\color{red}G & \color{blue}2 & \color{green}D &\color{orange}O & A \\
\color{red}L & \color{blue}7 & \color{green}I &\color{orange}4 & F \\
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}C & \color{green}N &\color{orange}9 & K \\
\color{red}6 & \color{blue}H & \color{green}3 &\color{orange}E & P \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\color{red}6 & \color{blue}C & \color{green}I &\color{orange}O & 5 \\
\color{red}B & \color{blue}H & \color{green}N &\color{orange}4 & A \\
\color{red}G & \color{blue}M & \color{green}3 &\color{orange}9 & F \\
\color{red}L & \color{blue}2 & \color{green}8 &\color{orange}E & K \\
\color{red}1 & \color{blue}7 & \color{green}D &\color{orange}J & P \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\color{red}1 &\color{red}6 &\color{red}B &\color{red}G &\color{red}L \\
\color{blue}2& \color{blue}7& \color{blue}C& \color{blue}H& \color{blue}M \\
\color{green}3& \color{green}8& \color{green}D& \color{green}I& \color{green}N \\
\color{orange}4 &\color{orange}9 &\color{orange}E &\color{orange}J &\color{orange}O \\
5 & A & F & K & P \\
\end{array}
$$

So we know that we can solve the case $N=25, K=5$ in $6$ iterations optimally. What can we do when we add $5$ more items/people? Can we reach the lower bound (computed earlier as $8$)? We can apply the same procedure (keeping items on the same column and shifting them a different amount of rows according to the column they belong). We will perform this "move" one more time compared to our squared $5\times5$ table, since we now have 6 rows. So this means 6 iterations. At the end of these 6 iterations we end up with numbers that haven't been paired **only** with other numbers in their column  (exactly as it was happening with the square tables).

**UPDATE**: No, this method will not work as the number of rows is not prime (in our case the second and third columns will go into cycles without visiting every row position). It is interesting to note that it *would work* if we had $N=35$ $K=5$ and thus having 7 rows. For the $N=30$ $K=5$ case my earlier incorrect "solution" was assuming that I will pair all numbers from other columns in 6 iterations. Then I was able to create all remaining pairings with 3 iterations, for a total of 9 iterations. Now I have to revisit the problem and see if I can indeed achieve this kind of pairing is 6 iterations.

Comment: @JDiMatteo seems I jumped the gun. There was a flaw in my reasoning that I discovered (edited the answer). My algorithm is not universal for all square N. It seems that it is working only for prime $\sqrt{N}$. Moreover, my method for solving the (30,5) problem is not valid. I will think about the problem more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution in 10 iterations to n=30 and k=5.  This is the result of a randomized greedy algorithm (which isn't guaranteed to succeed):

```
Iteration 1
  -- group 1: [27, 17, 0, 15, 8]
  -- group 2: [7, 25, 20, 14, 13]
  -- group 3: [24, 18, 22, 10, 19]
  -- group 4: [11, 26, 29, 9, 12]
  -- group 5: [23, 21, 6, 28, 3]
  -- group 6: [16, 5, 1, 4, 2]

Iteration 2
  -- group 1: [26, 21, 0, 13, 4]
  -- group 2: [16, 29, 19, 28, 14]
  -- group 3: [1, 8, 3, 9, 7]
  -- group 4: [12, 22, 23, 27, 20]
  -- group 5: [5, 24, 17, 6, 25]
  -- group 6: [2, 15, 11, 18, 10]

Iteration 3
  -- group 1: [19, 23, 11, 13, 1]
  -- group 2: [5, 3, 22, 0, 29]
  -- group 3: [6, 20, 18, 8, 4]
  -- group 4: [10, 12, 17, 7, 21]
  -- group 5: [24, 14, 9, 27, 2]
  -- group 6: [26, 25, 16, 15, 28]

Iteration 4
  -- group 1: [16, 24, 7, 11, 0]
  -- group 2: [25, 8, 2, 23, 29]
  -- group 3: [14, 4, 22, 15, 9]
  -- group 4: [19, 3, 20, 26, 17]
  -- group 5: [21, 27, 1, 18, 28]
  -- group 6: [6, 10, 13, 5, 12]

Iteration 5
  -- group 1: [4, 25, 11, 3, 27]
  -- group 2: [23, 26, 14, 18, 5]
  -- group 3: [20, 1, 10, 0, 28]
  -- group 4: [29, 7, 15, 6, 19]
  -- group 5: [16, 12, 8, 24, 13]
  -- group 6: [17, 22, 2, 21, 9]

Iteration 6
  -- group 1: [28, 2, 12, 19, 4]
  -- group 2: [9, 16, 18, 20, 13]
  -- group 3: [5, 7, 27, 26, 8]
  -- group 4: [1, 29, 17, 14, 10]
  -- group 5: [15, 3, 24, 23, 21]
  -- group 6: [25, 22, 11, 6, 0]

Iteration 7
  -- group 1: [1, 22, 26, 24, 28]
  -- group 2: [27, 16, 10, 3, 23]
  -- group 3: [25, 9, 19, 5, 21]
  -- group 4: [20, 15, 2, 13, 29]
  -- group 5: [11, 8, 14, 0, 12]
  -- group 6: [6, 18, 7, 4, 17]

Iteration 8
  -- group 1: [3, 13, 22, 28, 8]
  -- group 2: [12, 1, 25, 15, 18]
  -- group 3: [17, 23, 11, 0, 9]
  -- group 4: [6, 27, 16, 2, 26]
  -- group 5: [14, 21, 29, 20, 24]
  -- group 6: [19, 10, 4, 7, 5]

Iteration 9
  -- group 1: [8, 19, 27, 0, 13]
  -- group 2: [22, 7, 28, 17, 16]
  -- group 3: [26, 10, 9, 6, 14]
  -- group 4: [12, 3, 2, 18, 29]
  -- group 5: [24, 4, 23, 11, 21]
  -- group 6: [1, 15, 5, 20, 25]

Iteration 10
  -- group 1: [0, 2, 7, 23, 18]
  -- group 2: [22, 15, 29, 4, 27]
  -- group 3: [12, 17, 13, 3, 14]
  -- group 4: [21, 16, 8, 10, 25]
  -- group 5: [5, 11, 28, 20, 9]
  -- group 6: [6, 1, 19, 24, 26]
```