# Number of 4-player games in a tournament

Tags: combinatorics

I have seen a lot of posts online about the number of games in a tournament for 2 player games. But what if it's a 4-player game (say Ludo).

Consider a scenario where there are 12 people participating in a Ludo tournament. Each game in the tournament is a 4-player game. Is it possible to schedule the games such that each player plays every other player just once? If yes, how many games will there be in total in the tournament?

Can this be generalized for m players in an n-player game tournament?

Comment: Note that in a 4-player game, each player has three opponents in every game. So for each player to play every other player precisely once, certainly the number of other players must be a multiple of three. That is, the total number of players must be 1 more than a multiple of 3. So in general it is not possible to schedule the games in such a way.

Comment: @Servaes So the smallest tournament that we cannot immediately reject as impossible would be $16$, with 4 parallel games each round and 5 rounds. Is it possible? I don't know. Also, [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58922/rearrangement-of-groups-such-that-no-two-members-meet-again?rq=1).

Comment: @Arthur this is analogous to Kirkman's schoolgirl problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem).  In particular you seem to be looking for some sort of Steiner system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system).

Comment: @Servaes so it seems that in general for a n-player game, we need to have a (n-1)*x + 1 players?
That's a necessary condition, is it also sufficient?

Comment: @Arthur, it 'could' also be possible for 4 (obv), 7, 10, 13 as well, cant it? Why 16?

Comment: @user7427 Because with 7, 10 and 13 then you can't divide the players evenly into four people per table. With 4 I wouldn't really call it a tournament, but yes that's obviously possible.

Comment: @Arthur why does it have to be divisible? Maybe I am missing a very obvious connection?

Comment: I mean you can have 3 players (abc) in a 2-player game tournament with each playing each other once. (ab, ac, bc). The number of players (3) isnt divisible by the the number of people that can play in a single game(2). Is there a reason that should be the case in a 4-player game tournament?
The games dont have to run parallely. Is there any other reason it should be divisible?

Comment: The bridge players have a Howell movement that pairs each player with every other as partner and opposes each other twice. You can use that and ignore the partners

Comment: @user74207 I guess you don't _have_ to. But if you're organising a tournament, allowing all players to play in all rounds is a nice thing to strive for.